# Is there a function in R that can return an element of a dataframe based on its neighboring row elements?

Tags: r, function, tidyverse, lda, topic-modeling

I am doing topic modeling, and I have a dataframe (or tibble from tidyverse) with topic-word probabilities like so:

[dataframe with topic-word probabilities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BFWj.png)

All words appear 9 times, as I have a model with 9 topics, and their topic probabilities are found in the beta column. I would like to be able to call the beta value for each word and its associated topic like this:

beta_w_t = f(w,t)

I have experimented with the which function, but it doesn't seem to do the job. Is their such a function built into R, or do I have to define one myself?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  In particular, here you should post your input dataset using `dput()` rather than as an image and also post your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [`filter()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter.html) from dplyr? If I understand your question correct, this is what you need to do
`beta_wx_t3 <- filter(your_table, topic == 3 & str_detect(term, 'x')` to filter out topic 3 and a term that contains 'x'

`str_detect()` is useful if you want to get partial matches, but you could also use `term == 'x'` if you like

Also if you search specific action words (such as filter in this case) along with *tidyverse*, you generally get to the function you would need (or a stack exchange hint for a user written function for the same) within 5 mins!

Tidyverse is a nice R ecosystem with many packages with functions written out using action words (verbs) with great documentation in easy to understand format. I've found myself adding this keword to most of my R related Google searches!

[dplyr reference](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org)

Comment: Ah many thanks mate. I scoured the web for such a function, but I probably should have used the search word "filter" instead of my other attempts. Anyway it works, so thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help out. If your question was satisfactorily answered, you should consider accepting the answer by clicking on the green check mark on the left. Doing this keeps the community rewarded for useful answers and questions. Thank you!